# Twilio complication

Tags: twilio, twimlet

I'm new to Twilio, and I'm struggling with one task. I want to do the following:

Customer A calls the Twilio number. Twilio forwards the call to the sequence of number (I have used twimlet findme to forward the call). In this scenario, if the first number does not answer the call. Instead, it will be forwarded to the other number in the sequence and so on.

The problem I am facing occurs when the call is forwarded to the second number when the first one does not answer. It pauses for a long time, and after some second the bell rings. At that time the customer gets confused that whether he should continue or not.

So is there any way to notify the customer that the call is being continued?

There is a second scenario where Customer A calls the Twilio number. When the call is not answered or busy, the customer gets to hear the message from the company Operator that the "person is on another call" (in different languages). Is there any way to exclude the message from the company operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the way to solve your first question is to use [`answerOnBridge="true"` for your `<Dial>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#answeronbridge). That will keep the phone ringing until it is answered.

For your second question, you should set a [`timeout`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#timeout) on the call so that it doesn't reach an operator message.